# The listener function is not registered in the functional components

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, scroll, addeventlistener, react-functional-component

Using **Functional Component**, I am trying to find the **scroll position** of an element, but the **listener function** isn't **registering** as scrolling occurs. Can anyone explain why this is happening.

Here is the code for reference

```
export default function App() {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPOsition] = useState(0);
  const innerRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    console.log("handle scroll");
    // setScrollPOsition((scrollPosition) => scrollPosition + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (innerRef.current) {
      innerRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      return () => innerRef.current?.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span className={"scrollValue"}>
        scroll position of first header: {scrollPosition}
      </span>
      <h1 ref={innerRef}>Find My position on window</h1>
      <h2>Heading Element</h2>
      ...
      ...
      <h2>Heading Element</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/finding-the-scroll-position-of-an-element-osk650?file=/src/App.tsx:2705-2722)

Comment: The `<h1>` doesn't scroll, so the event never fires

Comment: Do you want to set the scroll position of the scrolling container? That would be your `<div className="App" />`

Comment: I want to display the scroll position of the first heading element in the container (which is `<div className="App">...</div>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen on the current scroll position you would make use of the `onScroll` event attribute.

I gave your scrolling `<div>` the `innerRef` and passed in `handleScroll` to your divs `onScroll`.

```
    <div className="App" ref={innerRef} onScroll={handleScroll}>
      <span ...
```

Additionally I had to add a fixed height and `overflow-y: scroll` to your `.App` class for the scroll event to be triggered:

```
// styles.css

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[image: Edit finding the scroll position of an element (forked)]